# What is a bootstrap-proxy in Chef?

Tags: proxy, chef-infra, bootstrapping

I am looking at this http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2375 and I am a bit confused as to what this option is useful for. I understand the idea of a proxy node in general as described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Can someone explain the use of a bootstrap-proxy in Chef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the bootstrap-proxy allows you to specify a HTTP proxy server when setting up your servers.

This is probably not a big deal for most people, but there are a few cases where you need/want an HTTP proxy.

1. Some networks are set up to require the use of an HTTP proxy in order to make outbound HTTP connections. This can provide some added security as well as a wealth of control on the part of the network admin. Without http proxy support the knife bootstrap command would be unable to make any HTTP connections.
2. Added an HTTP proxy as a cache can make commands like apt-get run much faster, especially on a slow connection. Essentially your proxy can cache any packages you download while the first server won't see much of a difference, any subsequent servers will download packages directly from the cache which can be much faster.

Comment: So how could we add authentication details when using this command? I have asked a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330757/bootstrapping-client-machine-behind-a-proxy-server-using-chef. Can you please check.

Comment: Have you tried adding a proxy url like this: http:// username:password@foo.bar:8080